# Different result for Regexp match with Rails and Rubular?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I am using Rails 4.0.0 with Ruby 2.0.0 p247. I am writing an URL regexp matcher but I have no idea why it does not work:

```
2.0.0-p247 :033 > REGEXP = %r{\Ahttps:\/\/#{ Rails.configuration.aws[:bucket] }\.s3(-#{Rails.configuration.aws[:region]}|)\.amazonaws\.com\/(?<path>uploads\/.+\/(?<filename>.+))\?.+\z}.freeze
 => /\Ahttps:\/\/test-gem\.s3(-eu-west-1|)\.amazonaws\.com\/(?<path>uploads\/.+\/(?<filename>.+))\?.+\z/
2.0.0-p247 :034 > url = "https://test-gem.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2alrg16mvx6r-29590d114fb3257846c1a03330418da9/3031674-poster-p-1-for-25.jpg"
 => "https://test-gem.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2alrg16mvx6r-29590d114fb3257846c1a03330418da9/3031674-poster-p-1-for-25.jpg"
2.0.0-p247 :035 > REGEXP.match(url)
 => nil
```

But when I try to debug in things like [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/YH3SdM6RQS), it does work. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `\?.+` in the end if your regexp

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bug with Ruby 2.0.0.  I'm using 2.1.3 and it works like you'd expect.

```
> r = /\Ahttps:\/\/test-gem\.s3(\A-eu-west-1\z|)\.amazonaws\.com\/(?<path>uploads\/.+\/(?<filename>.+))\z/
=> /\Ahttps:\/\/test-gem\.s3(\A-eu-west-1\z|)\.amazonaws\.com\/(?<path>uploads\/.+\/(?<filename>.+))\z/
> r.match("https://test-gem.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2alrg16mvx6r-29590d114fb3257846c1a03330418da9/3031674-poster-p-1-for-25.jpg")
=> #<MatchData
 "https://test-gem.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2alrg16mvx6r-29590d114fb3257846c1a03330418da9/3031674-poster-p-1-for-25.jpg"
 path:"uploads/2alrg16mvx6r-29590d114fb3257846c1a03330418da9/3031674-poster-p-1-for-25.jpg"
 filename:"3031674-poster-p-1-for-25.jpg">
```

Comment: Hi Philip, the r you have used is different from mine. When I use mine it still doesn't work. When I follow @Doguita to remove `\?.+` (but not `\z`), it works. So I have to give this one to @Doguita.... Thanks for answering!